# Ordinal numbers in select

Tags: sql, oracle11g

First sorry for my bad english it's not my native language :(

I'm kinda new in Oracle and I need help with following. I have several records with same ID, several values (which can be same) and different creation date. 
I would like to select an ordinal number for IDs which have same value, but different date.

For example

```
ID     | Value    | Date    | Number

A      | Value1   | 01.11.  | 1

A      | Value1   | 02.11.  | 2

A      | Value2   | 03.11.  | null

A      | Value2   | 01.11.  | null

B      | Value1   | 01.11.  | 1

B      | Value1   | 03.11.  | 2

B      | Value2   | 01.11.  | null

C      | Value1   | 01.11.  | 1

C      | Value2   | 01.11.  | null
```

So for every ID in first coloumn where I have Value1 I want to have increment and for the rest of the values I don't need to have anything.

I hope I'm not posting double question I have tried to look it up, but I couldn't find any answer.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Will accept one instead of null for other values.

Comment: This would be much simpler if you accepted 1 instead of null for instances where there was only one record.

Comment: Ok. I can accept one and solve it with decode :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is `row_number()` to get the sequential value and `rank()` to rank the values.  You only want the first set to be enumerated.  "First" corresponds to `rank()` having a value of `1`.  The rest get `NULL`:

```
select id, value, date,
       (case when rank() over (partition by id order by value) = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by id order by value)
        end) as number
from table t;
```

EDIT:

I realize that you might actually want the first value by *time* and not some other ordering.  For that, use `keep` instead of `rank()`:

```
select id, value, date,
       (case when value = max(value) keep (dense_rank first order by value) over (partition by id)
             then row_number() over (partition by id order by value)
        end) as number
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Hope I understood correctly:

```
with my_table as (
  select 'A' ID, 'Value1' value, '01.11.' dt, 1 num from dual union all
  select 'A', 'Value1', '02.11.', 2    from dual union all
  select 'A', 'Value2', '03.11.', null from dual union all
  select 'A', 'Value2', '01.11.', null from dual union all
  select 'B', 'Value1', '01.11.', 1    from dual union all
  select 'B', 'Value1', '03.11.', 2    from dual union all
  select 'B', 'Value2', '01.11.', null from dual union all
  select 'C', 'Value1', '01.11.', 1    from dual union all
  select 'C', 'Value2', '01.11.', null from dual)
select *
  from (select t.*, count(distinct dt) over (partition by value, id) diff_cnt
          from my_table t) tt
 where tt.diff_cnt > 1;
```

result:

```
ID VALUE  DT           NUM   DIFF_CNT
-- ------ ------ ---------- ----------
 A Value1 01.11.         1      2
 A Value1 02.11.         2      2
 B Value1 01.11.         1      2
 B Value1 03.11.         2      2
 A Value2 01.11.                2
 A Value2 03.11.                2
```